# Exposed filter slider for numbers

Tags: 7, entities, views, javascript

I am creating real estate website and as exposed filter for search in views i have a price.

Core view options are sufficient but maybe not so user friendly (as i have to explain in details how to input price, like dont use dots or spaces) so i was thinking of using slider so user can pick price range (for example from 10.000 up to 100.000).

I am not good at coding so was looking for module that does this ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is also the [Better Exposed Filters](http://drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters) module.

If you use the latest dev version there is support for jQuery UI slider, which was recently committed from a patch at http://drupal.org/node/1627524

It allows the use of a jQuery UI slider for any numeric filter (except date filters, which are technically an extension of the numeric filter).

Comment: I did not yet try dev version. Can it also catch range or its slider where you can choose one value only ?

Comment: If you select BETWEEN or NOT BETWEEN for your filter operator it will be a range, otherwise it will be a single slider.

Answer (score 4):

[Select With Style](http://drupal.org/project/select_with_style)

> When the widget is used as a filter (e.g. in combination with [Views
>   Global Filter](http://drupal.org/project/global_filter)) the slider becomes a range slider with two sliding
>   handles to set "from" and "to" range values.

[image]

[Contextual Range Filter](http://drupal.org/project/contextual_range_filter)

> Views Contextual Range Filter is a simple plugin for Views that adds
>   the option to contextually filter, not just by a single value, but
>   also by range.
>
> Numeric (float, integer), alphabetical (string) and list ranges are
>   all supported.
>
> Node ids, user ids and even taxonomy term ids are all special cases of
>   integers so will work also.
>
> You may use the OR (+) and negate operators. You negate by ticking the
>   "Exclude" box on the Views Contextual filter configuration panel, in
>   the "More" section.

[image]

Comment: I installed all modules and its working fine on node field, but in views i am still stucked. As exposed filter in views i am using price field and only getting text area, although on node slider is enabled and working fine. In documentation it says that i dont have to do anything more (i dont see any new options anyway) but to enable slider on node field which i did. I really have no idea what am i missing.

Comment: I also tried this module with no success. I think it wasn't built from the ground up for views.

Answer (score 1):

If you work with Search API, you can easily use module [Search API Ranges](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_ranges).